# How to explain that I is needed for characteristic equation?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> $$\\A\mathbf v - \lambda \mathbf v=0$$
>   $$\\(A - \lambda) \mathbf v=0$$

since the equation looks like to be correct. how to explain that it is not? (without examples)

I know that$\ I$  makes no change for $\lambda \mathbf v$ and
i only found unpersuasive explains like this one "We needed to do this because without it we would have had the difference of a matrix, A, and a constant, λ, and this can’t be done." can't we subtract a scalar from a matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you put in quotes *is* the explanation. Why try to do this without an example? $2 \times 2$ should be convincing, particularly if you note the ambiguity: perhaps "subtracting  $\lambda$" should mean subtracting it from all four matrix entries, not just from the two on the diagonal. How would you distinguish?

Comment: I thought the same as the explanation that "we cannot subtract a scalar from a matrix and matrix subtraction must have the same size so we multiply the scalar by the identity matrix and it also changes nothing so that's one of its uses" that what i would have say in the presentation. But thinking about it again and again i didn't know how to explain why subtracting the scalar (only) changes the equation

Comment: The problem isn't that "subtracting the scalar only" changes the equation. It's that "subtracting the scalar only" doesn't make any sense. It's like adding $2$ to a triangle. The reason you subtract $\lambda I$ is not just to "make sense", it's because that operation helps you do something useful: find the eigenvalues. I think that's the explanation for why you do it.

Comment: I'm already losing mind so why it doesn't make sense? (it is alright that characteristic equation is to find eigenvalues if i have the matrix)

Comment: It "doesn't make sense" because someone reading it would not know what it meant. It makes sense to you only because you know in advance what it is _supposed_ to mean. I'm sorry you're losing your mind. I don't think there's more I can say to help you.

Comment: Many thanks for your patience.

Comment: Could i say that it's because of the distributive law (A-B)C=AC-BC, and B here is a scalar not a matrix or that is wrong?

Comment: It's just plain wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The size of $A$ and $\lambda$ are not the same, hence the subtraction is not well defined.

While you can define $A- \lambda = A - \lambda I$, until you do so, the subtraction is not compatible and it might not be clear to other readers of what you are doing. We do call a diagonal matrix with identical diagonal entries [scalar matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ScalarMatrix.html) but I am not aware of the convention to drop the $I$ term. A problem which could arise is I might have difficulty answering what is the size of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're thinking of "substracting a scalar from a matrix" as "substracting a scalar from each element of a matrix". Let's call $\star$ this operation. Notice that $A-\lambda I \neq A\star \lambda$.  For instance, with $A = I$ and $\lambda = 1$ : 
$$ A - \lambda I = I - 1\times I = 0$$
while
$$A \star \lambda = I\star 1 = \pmatrix{1-1 & 0 -1 \\ 0 -1 & 1-1} = \pmatrix{0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0}$$

Thus the equation $Av - \lambda v = 0$ is **not** equivalent to $(A\star \lambda) v = 0$ ; but it is equivalent to $(A-\lambda I)v = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The field of scalars embeds into the matrix ring via $\lambda \mapsto \lambda I$, therefore you can identify $\lambda \in \Bbb{k}$ the field with $\lambda I$.  Thus the notation is well-defined.